# Deleting or omitting properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is the underscore.js function `omit` used as

```
query.options = _.omit(query.options, 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

equivalent to

```
delete temporaryQuery.options.a;
delete temporaryQuery.options.b;
delete temporaryQuery.options.c;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why not just look at its [sources](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1100)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. `_.omit` returns a new object and does not manipulate the existing data. By the way, you can take look at the [annotated source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) of Underscore, it is quite useful.

Comment: But since I am overwriting `query.options` with `query.options = _.omit(query.options, ...)`, I just thought I would obtain the exact same - even with some performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same.

"omit" copies the object, omitting the ones specified.

"delete" removes the property from the objrecr.